# Interacting programmatically with the equivalent of puts -ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-interpolation

I have a string, that I need to save escaped and then need to interact with programmatically without any backspaces:

```
    string = 'first=#{first_name}&last=#{last_name}'

    p string.to_s

=> "first=\#{first_name}&last=\#{last_name}"

    puts string.to_s

=> first=#{first_name}&last=#{last_name}
```

How do I get first=#{first_name}&last=#{last_name} to assign to a variable that I can scan, that does not have the "\" character?

Comment: Are you getting errors? The backslash doesn't seem like it should cause you problems as it's just an escape character, not a proper character in the string.

Comment: @jvillian Thanks, I was not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are equivalent:

```
# double quotes
"first=\#{first_name}&last=\#{last_name}"

# single quotes
'first=#{first_name}&last=#{last_name}'
```

In neither case is the backslash actually part of the string. If say `string.include? '\'` it will return false.

However, if you were to say `'\#{}'` the backslash would be part of the string. That's because in single quotes, `#{}` does not interpolate but is interpreted as literal characters.

Some example:

```
foo = 1
'#{foo}' # => "\#{foo}"
"#{foo}" # => "1"
'#{foo}' == "\#{foo}" # => true
"\#{foo}".include? '\' # => false
'\#{foo}'.include? '\' # => true
```

Note that `"\"` is an invalid string in ruby, but `'\'` is valid.

Comment: Thanks Max! I really appreciate it! :)